# "iPad Not Charging" Notification is annoying - Mavericks

Tags: macos, notifications

I get this really damn annoying banner every time I plug in my iPad and sometimes when I build and go in Xcode it loses connection with the iPad for a second and reconnects straight away.

Anyone know how to get rid of this notification? I know my iPad won't charge on this Mac Pro, it predates the iPad so it has less power going through the USB ports.

[image]

Comment: This *should* only appear when connected through a USB hub—perhaps standalone, on a monitor, or in a keyboard. Have you verified that the issue persists when directly plugged in to the Mac Pro?

Comment: Its an old mac pro, it has a lower amperage than the newer macs created after the original iPad was released.

Comment: That does not change the fact that the alert *should* (note my original phrasing; it's not ambiguous) only happen when connected to a USB hub of some sort. That's why I asked a clarifying question that you have not bothered to actually answer.

Comment: I'm plugging it into the computer directly, no hub, this isn't unfamiliar behavior, I already know it's not going to charge, it's a limitation with an old Mac. What I want is to get rid of the annoying notification. Previous iterations of OS X was not notifying on the computer at all, it would just show on the iPad that it wasn't charging,

Comment: Have you tried using a powered USB hub that provides enough juice to actually charge the iPad?

Comment: He's asking how to get rid of the message, not how to charge his iPad.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To turn off notifications:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.usbd NoiPadNotifications -bool YES
sudo killall usbd
```

To turn them back on:

```
sudo defaults delete com.apple.usbd NoiPadNotifications
```

Via [Craig Hockenberry](http://furbo.org/2013/12/05/ipad-not-annoying/)